# Sublime text 3 with Git-Bash

Tags: sublimetext3, git-bash

I was wondering how you can open Sublime text 3 with Git-Bash I keep getting errors saying that bash: subl: command not found does anyone know how to get the file to open up??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the folder containing `subl.exe` to your `PATH`. Here's how to do that in Windows 10:

1. Open the Windows menu and click on Settings.
2. In the search box, type in `path`. Choose the following from the dropdown: *Edit environment variables for your account*. This window should open:
   [image: Environment Variables window]
3. In the top pane, click on *Path*, then click the <kbd>Edit…</kbd> button. A new window will open up.
4. Click the <kbd>New</kbd> button, then (carefully) type in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`. This is assuming you used the installer and didn't choose a custom location for a portable install. If you do have a portable install, use the <kbd>Browse…</kbd> button and select the installation folder that way.
5. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the window, then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to close the other one. Finally, close out of Settings.
6. Completely close out of and restart Git Bash. `subl` should now be available on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the info I actually figured it out in a video a couple hours after I posted this. I do have another  question tho.